# Set active tabpanel mui from router nextjs

Tags: javascript, tabs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to set active tab using router pid

Here is how

```
function dashboard({ tabId }) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(""); 

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(tabId)
        if (tabId) {
            setValue(tabId);
        }

    }, [])
 
.......
}
```

Each of my TabPanel have a custom value how is the same I'm trying to pass as router parameter (pid)

The pid is get by getInitialProps

```
dashboard.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
    if (!query.pid) {
        return { tabId: 0 }
    }
    return { tabId: query.pid }
}
```

So the issue is, the tab is set as active but the content of the tab is not show ... Only the tab is set to active...

Tabs/TabPanel

```
<Tabs value={value} 
                            onChange={handleChange} 
                            initialSelectedIndex={1}
                            variant="fullWidth" 
                            aria-label="simple tabs example"
                            TabIndicatorProps={{
                                style: {
                                    display:'none',
                                }
                            }}
                            >
                        <Tab label="ACCUEIL" value="accueil" classes={{ root: classes.rootTab, selected: classes.selectedTab }} {...a11yProps(0)} />
                        <Tab label="GÉRER SA GAMME" value="ma-gamme" classes={{ root: classes.rootTab, selected: classes.selectedTab }} {...a11yProps(1)} />
                     .........
                        </Tabs>
                    </AppBar >

                    <TabPanel value="accueil" index={0}>

                    

                    </TabPanel>




                    <TabPanel value="ma-gamme" index={1}>

                    </TabPanel>
     ......
```

```
function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  
    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Container>
          <Box p={3}>
            {children}
          </Box>
          </Container>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  };
  


  function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }
```

Any help would be appreciate :)

---

Fixed by  juliomalves

I was using string value instead of value={index}

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually use `Tab`/`TabPanel`?

Comment: Tabs/TabPanel and other functions added to the post

Comment: You're passing `value` as a string and `index` as a number to your `TabPanel`s, `value === index` will never be true hence never showing its contents.

Comment: well thats pretty clear now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by juliomalves

I was using string value instead of value={index}